# multi-target project: run a command once after all builds are done

Tags: .net, .net-core, build, msbuild, csproj

I have a class library in an SDK style project. It targets several frameworks, e.g.:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net48;netcoreapp3.1;net5.0-windows;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

I have a target that I want to run after the builds, e.g.

```
<Target Name="WriteText" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="echo $(TargetFramework)"/> <!-- print out target framework -->
</Target>
```

If I run `dotnet build`, I can see from the console that the command is run after each build. **But I want it to be run just once after all builds are done.**

**How can I make it be run just once after all builds are done?**

I know I can work with conditions, so I could put a condition like

```
Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-windows'"
```

into my target to let it run after a certain framework build. But I need it to run after the LAST build, and which one is the last build? Is it

- the last one in my `<TargetFrameworks>` list? (No.)
- always a certain one in my `<TargetFrameworks>` list? (Seems so on my computer, at the moment. But can I be sure of it? What about other computers or future MSBuild versions?)

---

What I think I need is a way to manipulate a variable during builds, and then put a condition on that variable. Like this:

- There is an int variable `finishedBuilds` that is `0` before any build is done.
- There is a target that adds `1` to `finishedBuilds` after build. It has no condition, so it is called after each build.
- The condition for my desired command is then `Condition="'$(finishedBuilds)' == '4'"`.

**Is that possible, and if yes, how?**

Comment: Martin Ullrich answered my question in the comment section below [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080946/5333340) answer: use `AfterTargets="DispatchtoInnerBuilds"`.

Comment: This does not work. The output shows that my multi-target-post-build runs immediately after the first target is finished. Yes it runs only once but too early. Do you have a solution to that?