# Call script only once before all builds in a multi-targeting project

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, multitargeting, prebuild

I'm having a multiple targeting project using a script that generates classes out of a XSD. That should only be done once - for all build targets.

I found that [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50071932) but this solution does not work.

My *filtered* csproj contains these entries:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net472;net60-windows</TargetFrameworks>
...
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="call $(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Scripts\Python\XsdClassConverter2-Invoke.bat  ..." />
</Target>
```

I tried to change `BeforeTargets` and `Name` to `<Target Name="OuterPreBuild" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">` as suggested in linked post. But this does not work.

I'm sure that I'm missing something.

I tried to find all possible entries for `BeforeTargets` and found that [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN). But all of the possibilities does not sound like the setting that I'm looking for.

How do I've to call/setup my script to run only once?

Build environment is VS2022.

**EDIT**

I've a working solution:

```
<Target Name="GenerateXsdsCore">
  <Exec Command="call &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Scripts\Python\XsdClassConverter2-Invoke.bat&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Csv\Persistence\V1\V1_0.CsvCommon.xsd&quot; -n &quot;Toolkit.IO.Framework.Csv.Persistence.V1&quot; --field-specified-as-compare-default" />
  <Exec Command="call &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\Scripts\Python\XsdClassConverter2-Invoke.bat&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Licensing\Osi\Persistence\V1\V1_0.OpenSourceLicenseInformation.xsd&quot; -n &quot;Toolkit.IO.Framework.Licensing.Osi.Persistence.V1&quot; --field-specified-as-compare-default" />
</Target>
<Target Name="GenerateXsds" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds;BeforeBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="GenerateXsdsCore" Properties="TargetFramework=once" />
</Target>
```

The interesting point is `TargetFramework=once`. But this solution does not look like it should be done.

Comment: Is the project an SDK style project or a legacy style project? It appears that `DispatchToInnerBuilds` is part of SDK style projects, but not legacy style.

Comment: @JonathanDodds We're using only projects in SDK format even if they build against net472.

Comment: For current (VS2022) documentation for `BeforeTargets` see "[Target build order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/target-build-order?view=vs-2022)" and "[Extend the Visual Studio build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2022)".

Comment: There is not a target in the documentation for 'before all builds in a multi-target project' but the `Microsoft.Common.CrossTargeting.targets` defines the `DispatchToInnerBuilds` target which "Builds this project with /t:$(InnerTarget) /p:TargetFramework=X for each value X in $(TargetFrameworks)".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained how "this solution does not work".

If you create a target like the following, do you see the message appear in the build output? Does it appear once when there are multiple targets?

```xml
  <Target Name="TestTargetBeforeMultiFrameworkTargeting" BeforeTargets="DispatchToInnerBuilds">
    <Message Text="*** in TestTargetBeforeMultiFrameworkTargeting" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

This is testing that the technique in the answer to the "[How do I call my script before all the builds for only once in a multi-targeting project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071932/how-do-i-call-my-script-before-all-the-builds-for-only-once-in-a-multi-targeting)" question, works as advertised.

Comment: I added your code to my csproj. I clicked build for that project and I don't see your message. I've another solution but that does not work.